# How to determine whether a map click event has been set?

Tags: leaflet, events, event-listener

The [Evented](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#evented) section of the Leaflet documentation shows how to set an event listener for the `map` object:

> Leaflet deals with event listeners by reference, so if you want to add
>   a listener and then remove it, define it as a function:

```
function onClick(e) { ... }
map.on('click', onClick);
map.off('click', onClick);
```

In my application, there are various functions which may run on a map click event, depending on which mode the application is in (along the lines of having an "active tool" mode).

How can I determine which function is currently set as the map's `on click` event?

For example, if the line `map.on('click', xyz)` has been run, I would like to know that the current `on click` function is called `xyz`. And if `map.off('click', xyz)` has been run and there is no current click event I would like to know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property `._events` on the map which can be used to determine the presence of any event listeners:

`map._events.click.length` shows the number of listeners for the `click` event.

`map._events.click[0].fn` provides details of the first function that has been set to run on click, including its name via `map._events.click[0].fn.name`